# how to make UIBarButtonItem action is to view the login page (main view controller)

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have 2 class the first is view controller and another one tableviewcontroller i insert UIBarbuttonItem to insert mew user i want the add button to target to the login page of view controller how can i make that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right, and you want to link the UIBarButtonItem to another ViewController - you can do so simply by ctrl + dragging from the UIBarButtonItem to another ViewController to create a segue between them.

**Edit after comment:**

Step-by-step:

- First, ctrl + drag from your first ViewController to the second to create a segue connection between them
- Then, use your code and create a method

Create a method to call the segue:

```
-(void)myMethod {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier" sender:self];
}
```

Specify this method like Victor Johnson shows and once myMethod is called, you will be taken to the other ViewController.

Comment: but i make this programmatically by using   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    
  UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector()];
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

Comment: @EssamMohamed remember to put my line of code into an action you define in your code. Let me know if you have any further questions

Comment: call it wher how to call it on action ??

Comment: @EssamMohamed Could you please click the little checkbox thing to the left of my answer? To accept it?:) It will become green when clicked

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is switch from one view controller to another, you can ctrl + drag from the first view controller to create a segue between the two controllers, then give the segue a unique identifier (I'll use "SegueIdentifier").  Then in the first view controller create a new method that you can call each time the add button is pressed.  Then you can set that as the selector for your add button.

```
- (void)goToSecondViewController {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SegueIdentifier" sender:self];
}

UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(goToSecondViewController)];
```

Comment: 'Receiver (<TableViewControllerAccounts: 0x7a2ed470>) has no segue with identifier

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
  
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    
   UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(goToSecondViewController)];
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    
    
}

- (void)goToSecondViewController {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"adduser" sender:self];
}

Comment: i have another problem i want to connect add to signin button